# Is there a way to identify color type using Keynote for iOS

Tags: ipad, finder, keynote, color

I am wondering if you could find the exact color (using RGB, hex, CMYK, HSL, HSV, whatever!) of an object (like a rectangle) using Keynote for iOS.

I couldn’t find a way to do this on iOS, plus I don’t have a Mac (I'm on an iPad Air 2 running iOS 12).